# How can you grab the full text (body, headers, footers, textboxes, shapes, tables) from a .docx in Office.js?

Tags: office-js

I am working on an Add-in to text replace a document for some keywords. I need to be able to grab ALL text within the document to replace it.

All the examples online have use the "body" of the document, which doesn't include: headers, footers, tables, textboxes, nor shapes.

Is there any type of call that gets "ALL" text within a document?

Comment: Have you tried to get the range, and specify the properties in the *.load()* method?